# Parse error in phantomjs syntax

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have the following code, when I run it like so

```
phantomjs test-script.js http://phantomjs.org
```

I get an erorr of "SyntaxError: Parse Error". I'm newish to javascript and without a line number with the error I am lost. Here is the code

```
var args = require('system').args;
var url = "";

args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
        url = arg;
});


var page = require('webpage').create();

var pageLoaded = function({

page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js", function() {
            var data = page.evaluate(function() {
                return $("body").html();
            });

            var title = page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.title;
            });

            console.log('<title>' + title + '</title>');
            console.log(data);
            page.close();
            phantom.exit();
        });
    }
   });
});    

var try_to = function() {
  setTimeout(pageLoaded, 1000);
};

try_to();
```

I looked at [PhantomJS sometimes gives "parse error" messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942338/phantomjs-sometimes-gives-parse-error-messages) and [getting more information from phantomjs "SyntaxError: Parse error" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905664/getting-more-information-from-phantomjs-syntaxerror-parse-error-message) Neither give me more information to debug. I've checked multiple sites and am not getting the gzip issue mentioned in that first link. I think it's something w/ the code. As if I remove the try_to() function, all things work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting more information from phantomjs "SyntaxError: Parse error" message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905664/getting-more-information-from-phantomjs-syntaxerror-parse-error-message)

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste that js into [jslint](http://www.jslint.com), I just tried it and found many errors, some trivial, but some major.  You are missing a ) on your pageloaded function for starters.

Comment: I've done this and I don't see errors that are fixable. All of the { and ( line up in the code, unless I'm missing something. I can't find actual issues w/ the error that are output on jslint.

Comment: Var pageloaded = function() - you ar missing a )

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm an idiot. It should be var pageLoaded = function(). This helped. My apologies.

Comment: Just saw the other two comments. Browser fail. I appreciate the help. Sorry for the snarkieness. I haven't had much sleep.

Comment: No problem, happens to us all

Answer (score 0):

Use an online JavaScript validator such as http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html.